# get resource in directory java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

[image]

This is the structure of the project I am working on. I want to get an xsd file from the ValidateXML class.

```
// load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource("validacion.xsd");
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

Is it possible to get it from that path?
Is it possible to obtain it from that location?

Thank you!!

Comment: getResource would help you to reach resources folder, just use the file name with sub directory (if any)

Comment: @Sabareesh Muralidharan so can't find the file

Comment: The dir has to be under src/main/resources then use 
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(Name);